# Scale SKShapeNode from center?

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a SKShapeNode, and a label under one generic SKNode. If I try to scale that node, its position changes for no reason!. If I try to scale only the nodes it contains under it, it scales properly but not from the center, so it grows out to the up and right.

What am I doing wrong?
First before scale
[image: First before scale]

After scale
[image: After scale]

Notice its position moves up. Can't figure out why, does it even if I do it as an action or not. Also, the position is not changing based on log, but it appears the frame got bigger (though that is expected)

Steps to recreate issue:

set height and width
@h = 50
@w = 256

create rect with height and width
CGRectMake(0, 0, @w, @h)

get path for rect
UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithRect(rect).CGPath

create skshape node with path, set position

```
  antialiased: false,
  lineWidth: 1.0,
  strokeColor: SKColor.blackColor,
  fillColor: SKColor.whiteColor
```

Create sklabel, vertical center alignment, set position

create generic SKNode, no properties, add skshapenode and sklabel to it as children

Scale the generic SKNode.

Comment: can you add a picture to help describe your problem? Have you tried changing the anchor points ?

Comment: There appears to be no anchor points for SKShapeNode, and SKNode.

Comment: can you share some code.

Comment: my code isn't objective c (rubymotion) but logic is same, I'll show the pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SKLabelNode *labNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
labNode.fontSize = 12.0f;
labNode.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
labNode.text = @"SMASH";


SKSpriteNode *topWithText = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 30)];
topWithText.position = CGPointMake(100, 110);
[topWithText addChild:labNode];

SKSpriteNode *bottom = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 10)];
bottom.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);

[self addChild:topWithText];
[self addChild:bottom];

[topWithText runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                      [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                      [SKAction scaleBy:3.0 duration:3]
                                      ]]];
```

Comment: Same issue sadly, I'm trying to get a screen shot together (not sure if it will help though)

Comment: Can't figure out why yours scales right and mine doesn't. I messed with my positions some, I set the position for the SKNode instead of its children, and now it scales from the bottom right corner out up and right. I might try SKSpriteNode with the method you said.

Comment: you cant just make images with "smash" on it etc ? Why have you decided to do it your way.

Comment: The text is dynamic. I tried creating a texture, that fixed the scale issue, but unfortunately the quality came out pretty bad, and the left and bottom stroke are gone now. Not sure why

Comment: Good idea, but adding alpha became a problem after... it blends in with the back.

Comment: The rectangle parts. I wanted the box to be slightly see thru. That method fixes my issues with scaling, but then I can't use alpha, theres no win win for me lol

Comment: Ah I think I may have figured out a way changing the blending mode, I can ignore the background color

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I created an SKShapeNode.ellipseInRect which look perfectly fine when I didn't need to scale it. Yet as soon as I tried to scale it down to fit the text it was behind, it would randomly shrink towards the bottom left of the screen!

I did a little debugging, and the number that surprised me was that the position was set to (0, 0) even though the ellipse was in the top left corner of the screen! I then realized that by initializing with a rect the "anchor point" (even though SKShapeNodes don't technically have them) was at (0, 0) too. This behavior would explain my shrinking towards that point and your growing away from that point.

What solved this problem for me was instead of putting my position in the rect, set the position afterwards. Then it scaled around my node's center-point and not the screen origin. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With the SKShapeNode, this is impossible.

I solved it by adding a move Action to center the node manually.

You need to apply this to the y and x coordinates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).